Encountering difficulties activating Windows Defender Firewall on a Windows Server 2022 container instance
I aim to remotely connect to the system operating within a container based on a Windows Server 2022 Datacenter image. The initial container build configuration is:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server:ltsc2022 AS builder

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]

ENV RDP_PASSWORD=${RDP_PASSWORD}

RUN Install-WindowsFeature -Name RDS-RD-Server; \
    Install-WindowsFeature -Name Remote-Desktop-Services; \
    Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force;

RUN Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server' -Name 'fDenyTSConnections' -Value 0; \
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString (ConvertTo-SecureString RDP_PASSWORD -AsPlainText -Force) -AsPlainText -Force; \
    Set-LocalUser -Name 'Administrator' -Password $password; \
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services' -Name 'MinEncryptionLevel' -Value 1; \
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services' -Name 'AllowRemoteRPC' -Value 1;

FROM builder AS app

CMD ["powershell", "-NoExit"]

EXPOSE 3389

On Windows, I try to execute:
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop" ;

Return: Enable-NetFirewallRule : There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
From my interpretation, this message suggests that the firewall is either disabled or not running. I am confirming this by:
Get-Service -Name mpssvc

The status is "stopped".
When I try to turn it on, I get this:
Start-Service : Service 'Windows Defender Firewall (mpssvc)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service mpssvc on computer '.'.
What can I do to fix this problem?
